# How to enable a kernel driver?

Tags: centos, networking, linux-kernel, drivers, network-interface

I have two ethernet connections:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 15bb
    Kernel modules: e1000e
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1533
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

I *believe* I have the `e1000e` driver installed:

```
[root@home net]# lsmod | grep e1000e
e1000e                248519  0
ptp                    19231  2 igb,e1000e
```

Am I missing something to "attach" the driver to the ethernet controller?

Edit: Here's the relevant output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 7321.758557] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[ 7321.758560] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[ 7321.758762] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 7321.758785] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: irq 500 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 7322.764417] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
```

Comment: It looks as if you are not missing anything to "attach" the hardware to the kernel. You might need to configure the network though in order to use them. To be sure, check the system log, sometimes the hardware is identified, but the firmware is not present.

Comment: Hmm, I edited my post with the output from `dmesg`, which seems relevant.